# C# Task Scheduler Trigger not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, scheduled-tasks

I don't know if anyone can help with this but I am getting an error (object reference not set to an instance of an object) when I run my application.  Here is the code:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                myConnection2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, TaskName, Permission from ScheduledTasks s, Roles r WHERE s.ID= " + txtTaskID.Text, myConnection2);

                SqlDataReader rdr;
                rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string task = rdr["TaskName"].ToString();
                        Trigger tg = new RunOnceTrigger(DateTime.Now);
                        ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks();
                        Task t = st.OpenTask(task);
                        t.Triggers.Add(tg);
                        t.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It errors in the line t.Triggers.Add(tg).  I have stepped through the code and task is storing the right task name.  It just won't start the the task.

Comment: Could you mention what library/dll are you using for the ScheduledTasks functionality. Cuz, I am having difficulty finding the documentation online. From a google search, I see that people first create a new task [as opposed to opening it] and then add a trigger (without initializing the collection) and then save it, effectively running it at the said trigger time. Maybe if you read the documentation, maybe OpenTask is permitted for only existing tasks...

Comment: It is the Task Scheduler created by someone at Code Project.  Here it is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess would be that `t.Triggers` is currently equal to `null`.

You may need to instantiate a Triggers Collection in `t.Triggers` before trying to add anything to it.

Comment: I have gone through all of the sample code and can not figure out where they are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using it the way the author demonstrated. Whats the error that you are getting? Please post the exception message.

From the authors FAQ:

> Why am I getting access exceptions?
>
> This problem usually comes up for
>   clients who want to use the Task
>   Scheduler from ASP.NET code.
>   Ordinarily, such code runs in the
>   ASPNET account which has rather low
>   privilege and can't use the Task
>   Scheduler. The solution to this is to
>   set your code to run in another, more
>   privileged account. This is called
>   impersonation, and you can set it up
>   in your web.config file.
>
> The Task Scheduler doesn't require the
>   client to run with administrative
>   privilege, but if it's not, there will
>   be restrictions on what can be done. I
>   haven't found these to be
>   well-documented. However, until
>   recently it seemed that
>   non-administrators could see and
>   manipulate the tasks they created, but
>   no others. In Windows XP SP2, there
>   seems to be some generalization. In
>   the Explorer, there is a new Security
>   tab on the task Properties dialog box.
>   There is also do a little
>   documentation explaining that the file
>   permissions on the task will govern
>   what other users can do with them.
>   Read = look at it, Read/Execute = run
>   the task, Write = modify the task.

I was also wondering, that you havent provided any details for WHAT the task is supposed to do. As in something ought to happen, some program needs to be executed, when the task is run. I am assuming that you removed those lines before posting. If not, then maybe this library doesnt allow creating tasks without information on which application to execute at the scheduled time.

I use this particular library: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ ... its actively developed, the latest version was released last month, in may. It automatically uses the proper version of the Task Scheduler depending on the OS. Its just a personal preference ...

Comment: I have verified that it is running under an account that has rights to the server.  I might try to change the user that is associated with the task.  The task runs a batch file that copies files.  Regarding the library you linked, is it easy to query tasks and run tasks manually?  That is all I need to do right now is have a button that displays the tasks and a button that starts the task based on an ID I created in a database.

Comment: So I am trying out the other Task Scheduler and now when I try this foreach (RunningTask rt in ts.GetRunningTasks(true)) it tells me it is not supported.